# error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

Tags: java, android

I have this piece of code:

```js
 @
 Override
 protected void onPreEcecute() {

     progress = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, null, "Loading apps info...");
     super.onPreExecute();
```

I'm a noob when it comes to Android so i you can just kindly explain to me what my error means that would be great thank you

> Error:(142, 10) error: method does not override or implement a method
>   from a supertype

I got the code from a video on Youtube and it works perfectly there. Why does it not work here? if you need extra code for me to post please let me know

Comment: Once again, Java =/= JS. Look at the superclass method call and you'll see your typo

Comment: Questions about typos are off-topic.

Comment: I apologize for my mistakes thank you for pointing it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AsyncTask class  Is not `onPreEcecute()` you have a mispelling error is, the function that you should override is `onPreExecute()`

Comment: wow i feel retarded now. 
Thank you StackOverflow community I apologize for wasting your time.
I have another problem now it says that my app just stopped working... can you point me in a direction to solve this problem?

Comment: Add a new question with as much info as possible, copy here the link and I'll try to help you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38663339/application-to-get-list-of-installed-apps-not-working-in-android-studio-emulator